# Azure Liquid Template Parameter Comparison

Tags: azure-api-management, dotliquid

I have a simple test in an Azure API Manager Outgoing Policy

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <set-body template="liquid">
        {% if context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.param1 == 'test' %}
        Matched
        {% else %}
        Not Matched
        {% endif %}

        Hello : {{context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.param1}}
        </set-body>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

And I post

```
/echo/resource?param1=test
```

I get

```
Not Matched

Hello : test
```

I can't figure out the syntax to check the value for param1 and act accordingly in the body. I've not found any decent documentation on this which helps. I've tried this as well as

```
{% if context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.param1.Equals('test') %}
```

Can somebody advise on the syntax I need to check this? This should be trivial and it's driving me nuts! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me if I use a *variable*:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <set-variable name="param" value="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("param1"))" />    
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <set-body template="liquid">
    {% if context.Variables["param"] == 'test' %}
    Matched
    {% else %}
    Not Matched
    {% endif %}

    Hello : {{context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.param1}}
    </set-body>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Result:

```
Matched
Hello: test
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Markus's answer you can also do it like this

```
{% if context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.param1[0] == 'test' %}
```

It makes sense that it's an array of values and that's why the comparison was failing.